# "could not find hash function for hash operator" in my USER DEFINED-TYPE

Tags: postgresql

I have my own `User Defined-Type` named as `MYUDT` with operator class on my postgresql-9.3.4(CentOS release 6.5)

```
CREATE OPERATOR = (
    LEFTARG    = MYUDT,
    RIGHTARG   = MYUDT,
    PROCEDURE  = MYUDT_eq,
    NEGATOR    = <>,
    COMMUTATOR = =,
    JOIN       = eqjoinsel,
    HASHES,
    MERGES
);

CREATE OPERATOR CLASS MYUDT_OPS
DEFAULT FOR TYPE MYUDT USING BTREE AS
OPERATOR 1 <,
OPERATOR 2 <=,
OPERATOR 3 =,
OPERATOR 4 >=,
OPERATOR 5 >,
FUNCTION 1 MYUDT_OUT_CMP(MYUDT, MYUDT);
```

And I have two tables with `MYUDT` on which B-Tree index has been created.

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE1(C1 MYUDT, C2 VARCHAR(10));
CREATE INDEX IDX_MYUDT ON MY_TABLE1(C1);
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE2(C1 MYUDT, C2 VARCHAR(10));
```

Operators and functions needed for `<`,`<=`,`>`,`>=`,`=`,`<>` are there and it works fine with `nested Loop`/`Sort Merge` join though, `Hash join` doesn't work.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE1 A, MY_TABLE2 B WHERE A.C1=B.C1;
                                         QUERY PLAN                                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=10000000012.30..10000000026.38 rows=9 width=500)
   Hash Cond: (b.C1= a.C1)
   ->  Seq Scan on MY_TABLE2 b  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000012.90 rows=290 width=250)
   ->  Hash  (cost=12.22..12.22 rows=6 width=250)
         ->  Index Scan using IDX_MYUDT on MY_TABLE1 a  (cost=0.13..12.22 rows=6 width=250)
(5 rows)

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE1 A, MY_TABLE2 B WHERE A.C1=B.C1;
ERROR:  could not find hash function for hash operator 610980
```

I happend to hear that it needs to create `hash operator class` and I did it so.

```
CREATE FUNCTION MYUDT_hash(MYUDT)
RETURNS int LANGUAGE internal AS 'hashtext' IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OPERATOR CLASS MYUDT_HASH_OPS
DEFAULT FOR TYPE MYUDT USING hash AS
FUNCTION 1 MYUDT_hash(aria128);
```

but still it doesn't work and I need this one. What am I missing? Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: with function for `=` operator in hash operator class, It does work.

Comment: See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68915/postgresql-custom-operator-for-equality